# How can I set only time in NSDate variable?

Tags: ios, nsdate

I have NSDate variable and would like to change only time (date shouldn't be changed). Is it possible ?

Eg: user pick date interval in DatePicker date (If it's start date I would like to set time as 00:00:00, if it's end date, I set time as 23:59:59)

Thanks all for your help.

Regards, Alex.

Comment: You can't.  The NSDate object contains a single value which is essentially the number of milliseconds since the reference date.  You can, however, use NSCalendar and NSDateComponents to manipulate the individual components *as if* they were independent.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You'll want to use [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSDate *oldDate = datePicker.date; // Or however you get it.
unsigned unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay;
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:oldDate];
comps.hour   = 23;
comps.minute = 59;
comps.second = 59;
NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
```

Comment: How can I set TimeZone ?

Comment: I think this is solution, but Hours not set, only minutes and seconds were set up as 59:59. It's really need to set up timezone. Can I get the timezone from NSDate (in this example from oldDate variable ?

Comment: You can change `calendar.timeZone`

Comment: Thanks Kevin a lot. Couldn't you answer me one question else: how can get user's current timeZone (on the device)?

Comment: @LIAL The NSDate object does not contain a timezone -- it's always relative to UTC.

Comment: Looks like you can use `[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]` or `[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]`.

Comment: Thank it is really working my requirement was to add 12:00 AM time only but this formula is really effective

Answer (score 4):

The `NSDate` object cannot be changed.

You can create a new `NSDate` object from it. Take a look at the `- (id)dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds` method.

```
NSDate *newDate = [endDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:24.0f * 60.0f * 60.0f - 1.0f];
```

Answer (score 0):

When I only need to track the time, I don't use NSDate or NSTimeInterval.  Instead I use an NSinteger and store the "military" time, ie 0830 = 8:30 AM, 14:15 = 2:15 PM.