# Getting incorrect date from 24 hours format time string in Objective C and iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have to fetch date in format (YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss) from a 24 hours format (HH:mm) time string.

I have used the following code but I'm getting wrong output :

```
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [formatter setCalendar:[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian]];
 [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
 [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

 NSDate *myDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"13:54"];
```

And I am getting incorrect output : 2000-01-01 13:54:00 +0000

But I want the output like "2017-01-02 13:54:00"

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051915/ios-nsdate-from-string-with-time-only) but didn't get correct solution.

Comment: Are you printing the NSDate or a string formatted from an NSDate?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I am printing myDate (NSDate)

Comment: @AnandGautam That's the expected output when you print an NSDate. You need to print the formatted date string if you want the output you desire.

Comment: I tried using this format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" but getting nil output. here is my code : NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]; NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"13:54"];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is correct.

A date string without year / month / day information causes a date 2000/1/1 in `NSDateFormatter`.

You need to get the current date and replace the `hour` and `minute` components with those of the date string.

```
NSCalendar * calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *todayComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate *myDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"13:54"];
NSDateComponents *myDateComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:myDate];
todayComponents.minute = myDateComponents.minute;
todayComponents.hour = myDateComponents.hour;
NSDate *myCompleteDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:todayComponents];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss"];
NSString *myString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
```

Comment: (Mostly right, but instead of creating and using the `now` `NSDate`, the op should use his `myDate` `NSDate`. Also, declaring the string on a separate line from its initialization seems unnecessary.)

Comment: @Himanshu This is for getting current date in "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss" format. my question is different bro..

Comment: @LyndseyScott I tried with "myDate NSDate" instead of "now" in Himanshu's code, but getting incorrect output : 2000-01-01 19-24-00

Comment: @AnandGautam That's because you're not setting the date portion of your NSDate, only the time portion, so it's using a default date. You need to set the date portion if you want it to display a specific date. It won't just assume you mean today.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I understand what you'r trying to tell me, I tried setting the date portion in my NSDate but getting myDate  output as nil. Please check..

Comment: @AnandGautam I'm not a sir... But you're probably setting the date portion incorrectly. Here's an answer that's more applicable to your situation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17659571/2274694

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132098/discussion-between-anand-gautam-and-lyndsey-scott).

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:yourdateString];

NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]; // <- Local time zone
NSTimeZone *utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];

NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSInteger gmtOffset = [utcTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
            NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = currentGMTOffset - gmtOffset;



NSDate *destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval    sinceDate:date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatters = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatters setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy hh:mm"];

self.callDate = [dateFormatters stringFromDate: destinationDate];
```

Comment: @Hassan Thanks for your response, I tried your code & getting date "nil" and final output is coming "Mar 03 5877521 -08:-31"